# How to use different webdrivers based on environment

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, junit5, junit-jupiter, selenium-jupiter

I use selenium-jupiter. I am getting a webdriver from method arguments like this:

```
@Test
public void testWithChrome(ChromeDriver chromeDriver) {
          chromeDriver.get("someUrlHere");
}
```

Now I want to run tests on grid so I need to use webdriver based on environment. For example when developing tests on my PC I want to use (local) ChromeDriver, but when running tests on grid with Jenkins, I want to use RemoteDriver. 
So I need something like this: (That gives me local Chrome when env = 0 or gives me remote Chrome when env = 1 but it's not working)

```
int env = 0;

@Test
public void testWithChrome(
   (env == 0 ? ChromeDriver driver : RemoteDriver driver)) {
          driver.get("someUrlHere");
}
```

Comment: Have you checked out the official documentation for configuration options? https://bonigarcia.github.io/selenium-jupiter/

Comment: No, but I am checking it out right now, and it looks like, I can tune WebDriverManager to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: When configuring your Selenium extension programmatically you can force usage of a Selenium Grid by configuring its URL as follows (using JUnit 5 annotations):

```
abstract class UiTest {

    @RegisterExtension
    static SeleniumExtension seleniumExtension = new SeleniumExtension();     

    @BeforeAll
    static void setUpOnce() {

        boolean isRunningInCiEnvironment = ...

        if( isRunningInCiEnvironment ) {

           // this will force Selenium Jupiter to use a RemoteWebDriver
           seleniumExtension.getConfig().setSeleniumServerUrl("http://...");

        }

        // without above condition, a FirefoxDriver will be used locally
        seleniumExtension.addBrowsers(BrowserBuilder.firefox().build(););

   }       
}


class MyTest extends UiTest {

    // Use WebDriver interface in test method: concrete browser detected
    // at execution time (via @BeforeAll, inherited from parent class)
    @Test
    void my_test_Case(WebDriver webDriver) {

       webDriver.get(...)
       Assert.(...)        
    }
}
```

The problem in length [is decribed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54632176/how-to-programmatically-configure-webdriver-in-base-class-in-selenium-jupiter).

Comment: Thank you very much. Haven't tried it yet, but seems like the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think what would be better here is to have a method that is executed before any test (annotated with `@BeforeAll`) that determines what environment the script is being run in. It probably reads from some config file local vs grid. Once that is determined, assign the `driver` variable either an instance of `ChromeDriver` or `RemoteDriver`. From then on, your tests will pass around the `driver` instance which will be of type `WebDriver` because both `ChromeDriver` and `RemoteDriver` inherit from it.

```
WebDriver driver;

@BeforeAll
public void setup()
{
    // read from config file, etc. to determine if local or grid
    if (local)
    {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
    else
    {
        driver = new RemoteDriver();
    }
}

@Test
public void test()
{
    driver.get("someUrlHere");
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. How to do that in selenium-jupiter?

Comment: No idea. I hadn't heard of it before today. It seems odd to me to pass a specific driver around and to write tests for a specific browser. That kinda defeats the whole purpose of writing a test once and running it on X browsers. I would submit an issue on the github site and maybe someone there can help you. Maybe there are some tutorials or example code that you can reference.

Comment: I found an example that is somewhat similar to what you are looking for. It's at the bottom of the [Quick reference section](https://bonigarcia.github.io/selenium-jupiter/#quick-reference) and starts with `You can also inject WebDriver objects declaring them as constructor parameters, instead of as test method parameters.` with code below.

Comment: Injecting WebDriver in constructor seems to work the same way as injecting in method.

Comment: It seems that I will use your solutions and I will not use selenium-jupiter for now.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I upvoted your answer, but I don't have enough reputation so it doesn't show. Ok, I am going to accept your answer for now, because we don't have others, but I look for a selenium-jupiter specific solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with WebDriverManager that comes with this extension.

```
    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp()
    {
        switch(browser)
        {
            case "chrome" -> 
                {
                WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
                }
            case "firefox" ->
                {
                WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                }
            case "edge" ->
                {
                    WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
                    driver = new EdgeDriver();          
                }
        }
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
   }
```