# How to programmatically configure WebDriver in base class in Selenium Jupiter?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit, selenium-jupiter

I want to migrate existing Selenium-Tests based on JUnit 4 to JUnit 5. For this purpose, I want to make use of [Selenium-Jupiter](https://bonigarcia.github.io/selenium-jupiter/).

One requirement, that the tests must fulfill is, to be able to *switch the WebDriver implementation at runtime* - based on the execution environment - using **one common base class for all tests**:

- When executed on a developer machine (Windows 10), a FirefoxDriver should be used, launching a locally installed Firefox.
- In the CI-environment (CentOS 7), a RemoteWebDriver should be used, delegating test execution to a Selenium Grid

I already tried to configure a "Generic WebDriver" [according to documentation](https://bonigarcia.github.io/selenium-jupiter/#generic-driver), but I don't know how to achieve this for a RemoteWebDriver ("Example 2" should make things clearer).

With regards to content [this stackoverflow-posting is quite related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50857858/how-to-use-different-webdrivers-based-on-environment), but does not yield a satisfying answer.

**UPDATE:** I solved the problem by myself. See "Example 3"...

---

Hey [Boni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3877746/boni-garc%c3%ada), maybe you want to update the Selenium Jupiter documentation a bit. At least I had some problems, figuring it out... oh, and thanks a lot for the awesome work you have done with Selenium Jupiter (and the underlying WebDriverManger).

---

**Example 1: What works, but is not elegant**

```
@ExtendWith(SeleniumExtension.class)
class MyTest {

  @EnabledIfSystemProperty(named = "os.name", matches = "Windows 10")
  @Test
  void test_executed_with_local_firefox(FirefoxDriver ffDriver) {
     executeTestCaseWith(ffDriver);
  }

  @EnabledIfSystemProperty(named = "os.name", matches = "Linux")
  @Test
  void test_executed_with_firefox_from_selenium_grid(@DriverUrl("http://...") RemoteWebDriver remoteDriver) {
     executeTestCaseWith(remoteDriver);
  }

  void executeTestCaseWith(WebDriver webDriver) {
     webDriver.get(...)
     Assert(...)
  }
}
```

The problems I see hee, are:

1. Pretty verbose (tho' this might by handable with custom annotations)
2. Each test class needs **two** @Test-methods for *one* logical/semantical test case
3. The concrete WebDriver implementation is exposed, thus, allowing test authors to rely on WebDriver implementation detail (for example, Firefox profiles)

**Example 2: What I would like to do, but doesn't work, yet**

Base class, that does WebDriver configuration:

```
abstract class UiTest {

   @RegisterExtension
   static SeleniumExtension seleniumExtension = new SeleniumExtension();     

   @BeforeAll
   static void setUpOnce() {

     // This check is not the problem discussed here
     boolean isRunningInCiEnvironment = ...
     Browser firefox;

      if( ! isRunningInCiEnvironment ) {
        // This works
        firefox = BrowserBuilder.firefox().build();
      } else {
        // this does not exist yet!
        //firefox = BrowserBuilder.remoteWebDriver().url("http://...").build();

        // This executes, but does not behave as expected
        // The URL is pretty much ignored.
        firefox = BrowserBuilder.firefox().url("http://...").build();
      }

     seleniumExtension.addBrowsers(firefox);
   }       
}
```

In the test I would then only need to do sth. like this.

```
class MyTest extends UiTest {

  @Test
  void my_one_logic_test_case(WebDriver webDriver) {

     webDriver.get(...)
     Assert(...)        
  }
}
```

Note, how the type of the parameter is only WebDriver!

**Example 3: My current solution**

```
abstract class UiTest {

   @RegisterExtension
   static SeleniumExtension seleniumExtension = new SeleniumExtension();     

   @BeforeAll
   static void setUpOnce() {

     // This check is not the problem discussed here
     boolean isRunningInCiEnvironment = ...

      if( isRunningInCiEnvironment ) {
        // This is doing the trick!
        seleniumExtension.getConfig().setSeleniumServerUrl("http://...");
      }

     seleniumExtension.addBrowsers( BrowserBuilder.firefox().build() );
   }       
}
```

The concrete test can now be implemented as depicted in "Example 2".

Comment: For anyone who is also stumbling across the same problem, this is my **ugly workaround**:

1. In the base class (here: `UiTest`), I declare a String member, containing the Selenium Grid's URL and annotate it with `@DriverUrl` (this makes the tests pass in CI environment)

2. When executing a test locally, I _comment this annotation_, which leads to a Firefox being started on my local machine

Comment: The "ugly workaround" is not needed any more (see "Example 3").

Comment: Did you resolve issue #2? Does each test class still need to have 2 methods to execute one test in 2 browsers?

Comment: Yes, that's still the case...but note that this has also advantages: Like having explicit test results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@TestTemplate` and leverage browser configuration using two `browsers.json` files.

1. Write your test annotated with `@TestTemplate`:

```java
class MyTest {

  @TestTemplate
  void my_logic_test_case(WebDriver webDriver) {
    // ...       
  }
}
```

2. add a `browsers.json` to your classpath (Default, use local Firefox installation):

```json
{
  "browsers": [
    [
      {
        "type": "firefox"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

3. add a `browsers-ci.json` to your classpath (not default, uses Selenium Grid / RemoteWebDriver):

```json
{
  "browsers": [
    [
      {
        "type": "firefox",
        "capabilities": {
          "browserName": "firefox"
        },
        "arguments": [
          "--headless"
        ],
        "remoteUrl": "https://mygrid.com/wd/hub"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Now, you can run the test locally and it will use a local Firefox.
If you run your tests on your CI environment, configure your CI script to set the system property `sel.jup.browser.template.json.file` to point to `browsers-ci.json`.

For example, if you use Maven to run your Selenium-Jupiter tests:

```
mvn test -Dsel.jup.browser.template.json.file=classpath:browsers-ci.json
```